# What introductory courses on statistics are available online?

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for a full online course on college-introductory level statistics (and beyond). I've seen a few options on statistics.com ($600usd online courses ouch), and coursera (starts over a month from now).

I wonder if there are other good resources that could constitute a course on statistics (books seem to supplement courses well, but not replace them quite perfectly). Academic credit & certification options are a plus, but not necessary.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a series of three UC Berkeley courses on edX-

https://www.edx.org/course-list/allschools/statistics%20and%20data%20analysis/allcourses

You can register and view all the archived course material from past sessions. (On certain Coursera courses this is also possible by clicking 'Preview' if this is available.)

There's also Udacity (two statistics courses that I found)-

https://www.udacity.com/courses

For textbooks, Rice's Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis is one I remember fondly from university. While I used it mainly as a reference to complement lectures, the tone and progression did strike me as appropriate for self-study.

Answer (score 1):

check videolectures.net there are tons of video lectures that are nice.
for example check this page:

http://videolectures.net/Top/Mathematics/Statistics/

Comment: This is very cool! Not quite the full course that I'd like, but cool!! Thanks for sharing it.  I'm still hoping for a full course as I don't really know what I don't know in this area, so I want something to lead me through the learning process.

Comment: I usually choose a topic and then look for tutorials, video lectures, books,... about that specifically. This way you can reach  high quality material.

Answer (score 1):

Each time i check for a online course of this kind, i use to watch the courses from MIT, to see if they have something interesting. In this case i have found [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2005/lecture-notes/). Hope that helps you. Regards.

Comment: The MIT courseware is certainly cool, but I feel like without the lectures they're kind of thin on content. It's nice to have the outline, material, assignments, exams, etc, but the lecture notes alone aren't enough to teach me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

A [YouTube search yields](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=introduction%20to%20statistics&filters=playlist&lclk=playlist) what seems to be some good results

Comment: yup, lots of good resources, but again, just resources, not a comprehensive guide, I could toil away a lifetime watching instructional material, I want a concise set of activities that teach me the material efficiently. I'm not qualified to lead myself through that process.

Answer (score 1):

I like http://www.statlect.com/

Very good for an introductory course I would say.