# What are some good statistics resources?

Tags: statistics, education, online-resources

A year ago, I took a statistics course at my university. The course was based on Rice's "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis". Apart from the fact that I did not find the book terribly good, I found that the lectures did not aid me a lot in understanding the material either. I did pass the course, but I didn't feel I *really* understood the material.

Fast forward a year. I have now come to realise that statistics can be a very interesting and useful subject, but I haven't done any statistics ever since the course I just mentioned. I'm thinking of doing some statistics courses for my Master's degree, though.

**Question**: do you know any good resources (video lectures, books, solved problems) which I can use to brush up my statistics knowledge? I like books that have a large number of solved problems and worked examples, so I can check whether I actually solved the problems correctly.

Comment: Check out the massive open on-line classes on statistics on udacity.com and coursera.com.  Several of these use R (which is a good thing IMHO).

Comment: [See these threads](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bstatistics%5d%20%5breference-request%5d%20book%20recommendation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What introductory courses on statistics are available online?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472630/what-introductory-courses-on-statistics-are-available-online)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51785/321264